# Trying to send parameters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-template-filters

I'm trying to obtain dedicated urls of some products that I have in my shop.html page. I have five products that I named "cards": (Ysera, Neltharion, Nozdormu, Alexstrasza, Malygos). Each card should have a dedicated url (localhost:8000/card/**1**/, localhost:8000/card/**2**/, etc). but instead of obtaining that url, django launch me that message:

> *DoesNotExist at /card/1/ card matching query does not exist*.

I imported properly the class model "card" in my views.py, in fact I am justly using card in a filter function to obtain all products in shop.html. please look my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from dracoin.apps.synopticup.models import card
from dracoin.apps.home.forms import ContactForm,LoginForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    



def index(request):
    return render_to_response('home/index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def landing(request):
    return render_to_response('home/landing.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def shop(request):
    tarj = card.objects.filter(status=True)
    ctx = {'tarjetas':tarj}
    return render_to_response('home/shop.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def singleCard(request,id_tarj):    
    tarj = card.objects.get(id=id_tarj) 
    ctx = {'card':tarj}
    return render_to_response('home/singleCard.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

here my urls.py:

```
url(r'^card/(?P<id_tarj>.*)/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.singleCard',name='vista_single_card'),
```

My imported model:

```
class card(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

My singleCard.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Tarjeta {{card.nombre}} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h1>{{ card.nombre }}</h1><br> 
<p> {{ card.descripcion }}</p>        

{% endblock %}
```

I don't know if I have a wrong refering "card" class. But I try to apply other answers in this forum. For example:

[In Django, how do I objects.get, but return None when nothing is found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090302/in-django-how-do-i-objects-get-but-return-none-when-nothing-is-found)

[matching query does not exist Error in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508888/matching-query-does-not-exist-error-in-django)

[Django error - matching query does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813919/django-error-matching-query-does-not-exist)

I don't know if I commit a mistake applying these solutions. Including I try:

```
tarj = card.objects.filter(id=id_tarj)
```

Using this I obtain a blank page of my website...

apologizeme in advance my extensive question and if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

---

Answering to wolendranh I have an urls.py by app and the main urls.py.

Recently I'm learning django by my side and I can't understand how I can define my own consistent identifier in this case.

if it is still useful I put here a traceback generated with the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/card/1/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dracoin.apps.synopticup',
 'dracoin.apps.home')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/draicore/project/multilevel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/draicore/project/dracoin/dracoin/apps/home/views.py" in singleCard
  24.       tarj = card.objects.get(id=id_tarj) 
File "/home/draicore/project/multilevel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/draicore/project/multilevel/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  357.                 self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /card/1/
Exception Value: card matching query does not exist.
```

excuse me for prolong this question.

Comment: this means you dont have a card object with id 1 in your database. open a shell, and see what are valid ids of objects in the database

Comment: also try setting errors to be displayed on your webserver, will help you a lot - alternatively check the apache? error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As karthikr says in the comment, you don't have a card with id=1.

This is probably because you previously deleted and recreated a card. The id is an autoincrement field, which means the database does not reuse IDs that have been deleted. If you want your item to have a consistent identifier which you can always use to query it in the URL, you should probably define that as an explicit IntegerField (using another name than `id`), and query against that instead. Even better, use a slug rather than a numeric ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have few things to clarify:
1. Do you have a single urls.py file in your project? or separate for every app.
   If you have a separate like "your_project/card/urls" and it is included into main urls.py you should NOT use "card/" in your url. Because Django already knows that request is for that app.

```
r'^card/(?P<id_tarj>.*)/$' -> r'^(?P<id_tarj>.*)/$'
```

2. If it is in main urls.py try to replace:

   ```
   r'^card/(?P<id_tarj>.*)/$'
   ```

   to

   r'^card/(?P\d+))/$'

P.s.: I don't have anough reputation for comments, so I added an answer. Sorry.